# Search Firebase Query with array of unique keys

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have my schema set as follows.

[image]

Now i want to send the a string `chinohills7leavescafe101191514.19284` and want to check if there is any string in the `Chino Hills` or not.
I am confused to make any search query because i have not stored above string in fixed `childKey`
I know the schema should be like this but i cannot change the schema.

```
leaves-cafe
    codes
        Chino Hills
            -Kw0ZtwrPjyNh1_HJrkf
                codeValue: "chinohills7leavescafe101191514.19284"
```

Comment: Please show some code that you tried and also show the expanded structure of `Chino Hills` any child key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [queryOrderedByValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#data_order). It works the same ways as `queryOrderedByChild` and allows you to use `queryEqualToValue` to achieve the result you need since you can't alter your current schema.

Here's an example

```
// warning: untested code - just illustrating queryOrderedByValue

let ref = Database.database().reference().child("leaves-cafe").child("codes").child("Chino Hills")
let queryRef = ref.queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: "chinohills7leavescafe101191514.19284")

queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print("value does exists")
    } else {
        print("value doesn't exist")
    }
})
```

Your alternative option is to iterate over all nodes and check if the value exists manually as *3stud1ant3* suggested. However, note that this approach is both costy and a security risk. You would be downloading potentially a lot of data, and generally you shouldn't load unneeded data (especially if they're sensitive information, not sure if that's your case) on device; it's the equivalent of downloading all passwords off a database to check if the entered one matches a given user's.